# Comparing first line in multiple CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a folder containing about 130 .csv files that all *appear* to contain similar fields (column names).  However, based on some of the file names, I am under the impression that some of the .CSV files may have slightly diffrent schemas (e.g., xxxxxx_new_format.cvs, xxxxx_version_2.csv).  My thought is to copy the first line of each .csv into a text doc for comparison.

So I created the following script:

```
 Get-Content "C:\*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
   Select-Object -First 1 | Out-File "C:\compare.txt"
 }
```

which seemed to go into an infinite loop.

How should I attack this problem? If there is a better method for comparison (i.e., I should be using python) please let me know.

Comment: `Get-Content "C:*.csv" -TotalCount 1`

Comment: To have the filename next to each header I suggest `gci *.csv|%{$_.Fullname;gc $_ -totalcount 1}`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp2\*.csv" | 
    %{[pscustomobject]@{FileName=$_.FullName;Header=gc $_.FullName -TotalCount 1}} | 
        group Header
```